# Python kernel automatically changes back to base in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to connect to a different environment for jupyter notebook in VS Code. I have settings.json as in the following:

`"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\username\\.conda\\envs\\analytics\\python.exe"`

I have manually added python path in `select python interpreter`

I have tried almost every solution, but I am unable to change kernel. Whenever I `Reload Window` it selects the intended kernel for a few seconds and then it changes back to `base`. I have never encountered this problem before, I have just installed anaconda and VS Code on this system. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: I guess you choose `Select interpreter` through the `Command Palette` by pressing `Ctrl+P`. When you choose the `Select Interpreter` option, doesn't it bring you _all_ the installed python environemts?

Comment: it does but when i select intended interpreter it doesn't change on upper left corner

Comment: Do you have the Jupyter extension installed?

Comment: I have, that is why I am able to run basic code on base environment

Comment: Try `pip install --upgrade pyzmq`